# About PhoneGap inappbrowser video play stop

Tags: cordova

I use PhoneGap 2.4.0. for android app.

When I open external webpage(contain youtube video) with inappbrowser, the video play good.
But after closing webpage by done button, the audio playing does not stop.
To stop video sound, I had to turn off my phone.

It is big problem to me.
Last for a week I tried to fix it.

Can I get some help?

---

This is my code.

```
.......................

  function chamgae(juso) {
        var ref = window.open(juso, '_blank', 'location=yes');
        ref.close();
        }
..........................

<a href="#" onclick="chamgae('http://m.youtube.com')">

..........................
```

Or

```
.......................

      function chamgae(juso) {
            window.open(juso, '_blank', 'location=yes');
            }
    ..........................

    <a href="#" onclick="chamgae('http://m.youtube.com')">

    ..........................
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you do .close() after opening the InAppBrowser.

```
var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no');
ref.close();
```

I removed the .close() code and I got the same problem as you of continued playback. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, is set `_blank` to `_self` that will cause it to stop when you go back. I had this same issue and this is the only thing that I found that fixed that problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to track focus or blur event of the web view. You simply need to add listeners to the the window like this:-

```
var win = window.top;
win.onfocus = function() { };
win.onblur  = function() { fnDoSomething() };
function fnDoSomething(){
player=$f(document.getElementById('player_1'));
player.api('pause');
}
```

win.onblur is a called whenever the web view looses focus, any action can be performed in that listener.
As in above example I have called 'pause' method of vimeo player.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

After trying several solutions from SO i finally found a solution that works for me on Win10:

```
var ref = window.open(file, '_blank', 'location=yes,hardwareback=yes,fullscreen=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function () {
    ref.executeScript({ file: "videofix.js" });
});
```

videofix.js:

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];

let videoStopped = false;
// is executed every 100ms
var id = window.setInterval(function () {
    if (document.hidden && !videoStopped) {
        video.pause();
        videoStopped = true;
        // stop execution of this method
        window.clearInterval(id);
    }
}, 100);
```