# How can stop youtube video sound after close inappbrowser

Tags: youtube, cordova

How can stop youtube video sound after closing webview opened by inappbrowser(Android Phonegap 2.4.0 plugin)

I used two week to fix that problem and tired out..............

When I click 'Done' button to close webview(youtube page), the video still play in the background.

Even after shutting down app, can't stop video sound.
To stop video I had to turn off phone.

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

 function OpenWin(juso) {
        window.open(juso, '_blank', 'location=yes');
         }

</script>  


<body>
...................
<a href="#" onclick="OpenWin('http://m.youtube.com')"> 
...................
</body>
```

Is there any wrong in my code?
May I get some help?

Comment: see at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/49194410/5830773

Answer (score 1):

I am using Sencha Touch and using the following trick to stop the Youtube Video sound. You may take it as reference.

```
var ref = window.open(url,'_blank',options);
ref.addEventListener('exit',function(){
    Ext.defer(function(){
        ref.removeEventListener('exit',function(){
            console.log('Closed');
        });
        var ref2 = window.open('about:blank','_blank','hidden=yes');
        Ext.defer(function(){
            ref2.close();
        },350);
    },350);
});
```